# Logical else/if not working

Tags: php, if-statement

I have problem in logical `else``if` in PHP. This is in my menu:

```
?hal=daftar
?hal=Visi
?hal=berita
```

For my page:

```
if(isset($_GET['hal'])=='daftar'){
      include"daftar.php";
  }
  elseif(isset($_GET["hal"])=="Visi"){

      include"profil.php";
  }
  else if(isset($_GET['hal'])=='berita'){

      include"berita.php";
  }
  else
  {
echo"wrong"
}
```

Problem is why that appears only just page `daftar` or if i'm click in menu `?hal=Visi`, `?hal=berita` always appears page `daftar`.

Comment: Isset returns a bool value. And you try to compare it with string.

Answer (score 1):

[`isset`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.isset.php) only returns a boolean of `true` or `false` so it will never match a value other than `true` or `false`. To use `isset` with a comparison operator do this instead:

```
if (isset($_GET['hal']) && $_GET["hal"] == 'daftar'){
  include "daftar.php";
}
else if (isset($_GET["hal"]) && $_GET["hal"] == "Visi"){
  include "profil.php";
}
else if (isset($_GET['hal']) && $_GET["hal"] == 'berita'){
  include "berita.php";
}
else {
  echo "wrong"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will works fine :

```
$myvar = $_GET['hal'];
if($myvar =='daftar'){
      include"daftar.php";
  }
  else if($myvar =="Visi"){
      include"profil.php";
  }
  else if($myvar =='berita'){
      include"berita.php";
  }
  else
  {
echo"wrong"
}
```

Comment: there is not working for me because i'm using PHP Version 5.4

Answer (score -1):

You are comparing a bool value with a string in each condition as isset() returns a boolean